# Do we need the [flask-mega-tutorial] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Today, while browsing new questions, I noticed one with a rather strange tag: [flask-mega-tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-mega-tutorial). For the specific question, I edited out the tags and replaced it with [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), but it seems that it was not the only question using that tag. There's only a handful of questions under this tag, but it seems rather off-topic and way too specific.

Should anything be done about this tag? Perhaps removing it from the few questions that use it and get rid of it, or is it not worth the effort?

The tag description:

> The Flask Mega-Tutorial is a tutorial for Python beginner and intermediate developers that teaches web development with the Flask framework.

Comment: If there's only a handful, generally, you should be fine to go ahead and handle the removal yourself. I doubt there's any question about the appropriateness of this tag... (Especially since it can easily mislead users to assume they can just ask for a tutorial, without realizing that's a specific tutorial.)

Comment: Ok, cool, I've gone ahead and edited out the tag from all those questions, is there anything else I should (or can) do to get rid of the tag?

Comment: No. The tag will be deleted automatically when the cleanup script runs